# Удаление тега из переменной php, регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, составить регулярку.

Есть переменная, в которой содержится таблица < table>< tr>< td>...< /td>< /tr>< /table>, в некоторых ячейках встречаются ссылки < a href="...">sometext< /a>

Требуется удалить из переменной только теги ссылок, оставив их анкоры, т.е., sometext

Спасибо.

Приведу пример по просьбе

```
<table><tr>
<td><a href="http://fsdfsd.ru">Сайт</a> компании</td>
<td>Какая-то информация</td>
</tr></table>
```

Должно получиться

```
<table><tr>
<td>Сайт компании</td>
<td>Какая-то информация</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: напишите пример что должно получится

Comment: добавил пример для вас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('#<a.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i', '$1', $str);
```